# How to prove $f'(a)=0$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function, where $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a interval.

For each $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $X_c=\{x\in I;\;\;f(x)=c\}$.

The problem asks to show that if there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a\in I\cap \left (X_c\right)'$, then $f'(a)=0$.

I don't know how to start, so I would like hints. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: $(X_c)'$ is the set of accumulation points of $X_c$?

Comment: How can $c \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a value of $f$ if $f$ has a codomain of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes.

Comment: @Orangutango I correted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $a \in X_c'$ means that there is a sequence of points $(a_n)\in X_c \setminus \{a\}$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. Now look at $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(a_k)-f(a)}{a_k-a}$$

Comment: By $A$ do you mean $X_c$ ?

Comment: @user10444 Presumably $A$ should be $I$.

Comment: @AlexBecker But isn't $a$ a limit point of $X_c$ ?

Comment: @user10444 Ah yes, it should be $X_c$.

Comment: Can someone help me complete this, my thoughts are since $X_c$ is closed ( $X_c =f^{-1}(\{c\})$ and the inverse image of a closed set is closed when the function is continuous) then $a\in X_c$ hence $f(a)=c$ and the limit above becomes zero.